# Reading downloaded file objective-c

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, download, afnetworking

I am trying to read text file downloaded from my server.

```
-(void)downloadFile
{
NSURLRequest request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myserver.com/website/file.txt"]];
AFURLConnectionOperation *operation =   [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *filePath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"file.txt"];
operation.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:filePath append:NO];

[operation setCompletionBlock:^{
        NSLog(@"downloadComplete!");

        NSString *path;
        path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"file" ofType: @"txt"];
        NSString *data = [self readFile: path];
        NSLog(@"%@",data);
}];
[operation start];
}

-(NSString *)readFile:(NSString *)fileName

{
    NSLog(@"readFile");

    NSString *appFile = fileName;
    NSFileManager *fileManager=[NSFileManager defaultManager];
    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:appFile])
    {
        NSError *error= NULL;
        NSString *resultData = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile: appFile encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding error: &error];
        if (error == NULL)
            return resultData;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

It downloads the file successfully but I can't read file. Returns null. Probably I can't set file path correctly. I want to read file from device disk, not project bundle.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to read it from the bundle.  Why aren't you calling "[self readFile:filePath];"?

Comment: @Nicholas Hart sorry, I forgot adding readFile method. I updated my post...

Comment: It looks like you are trying to read "file.txt" from the bundle, not from the place where you saved it.  Use NSLog to output the value of "error" (in readFile:) and you will see I am right.

Comment: why don't you NSLog what the actual error is instead of letting it go to the wayside, the edit your question with the results? Just a thought.

Comment: I just realized.. There is no error. It returns "null" because [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:appFile] returns false because the file doesn't exists in the path I set. File is downloaded successfully and I see the file in simulator's application directory. But I don't know how I can call it.. Please look at this: http://i43.tinypic.com/wgqmao.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"file" ofType: @"txt"];
```

to

```
path = filePath;
```

Answer (score 0):

I made your stuff work, i dont know if you still need it

```
-(void)downloadFile
{
    CNMRouter *routext;

    routext = ((LDAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).router;

    [[[Singleton sharedClient]httpClient] setParameterEncoding:AFFormURLParameterEncoding];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request;

    if([routext postOrGet]){
        request = [[[Singleton sharedClient]httpClient]  requestWithMethod:@"GET"
                                                                      path:[routext getLoginURLPath:@"admin" andPassword:@"admin"]
                                                                parameters:nil];
    }else{

        request   = [[[Singleton sharedClient]httpClient]  requestWithMethod:@"POST"
                                                                        path:[routext getBackupUrl]
                                                                  parameters:[routext getBackupURLPath]];
    }


//    NSURLRequest request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myserver.com/website/file.txt"]];
    AFURLConnectionOperation *operation =   [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];



    [operation setCompletionBlock:^{
        NSLog(@"downloadComplete!");

        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSLog(@"%@", [paths objectAtIndex:0]);
        NSString *filePath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"file.txt"];
//        operation.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:filePath append:NO];

        NSString *path;
//        path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"file" ofType: @"txt"];
        path = filePath;
        NSString *data = [self readFile: path];
        NSLog(@"%@",data);
    }];
    [operation start];
}
```

I moved some stuf from its place but basicaly you were trying to get your file before it was even downloaded so i just put some stuff inside the succes block. Its working for me, thank you!